# How to route GridViewColumnHeader.Click event with EventToCommand and MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, command, mvvm-light, eventtocommand

This bigger code example below works. Now what I **really** want to route is the `GridViewColumnHeader.Click` event within the `EventTrigger`. Replacing `MouseMove` with `GridViewColumnHeader.Click` doesn't work. Any ideas on that?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" 
        GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
            <cmd:EventToCommand 
                Command="{Binding FooCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnA" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyA}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnB" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyB}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnC" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyC}"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: GridViewColumnHeader.Click ?

Comment: Yes. It is executed when I click on the header of the column. I'd like to initiate a sort then.

Comment: You can try with attached behaviors like Dan Parsonson suggests [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8057736/1698987).

Comment: the datagrid supports sorting Add SortMemberPath="PropertyA" to the colmn declaration.  Is sorting the only thing you want to accomplish with the header click?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Ended up using the DataGrid instead which supports sorting too via a CanUserSortColumns property (enabled by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the DataGrid instead which supports sorting by default.